# rails 3.1.12 - request.parameters missing user_id key value pair in after filter

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.1

In my request to a legacy system, i am logging the request and response(@legacy side). I implemented this by apply before and after filters to the api module base controller. But i am missing the `user_id` in the request.parameters hash in my after_filter. I check the request.parameters hash in before filter and the user_id is present.  Can any one give me an insight on why this is happening.

versions

```
ruby 1.9.3p547 (2014-05-14 revision 45962) [i686-linux]

rails 3.1.12
```

eg:

In before filter

```
{"search_params"=>{"d"=>"08/20/2014", "c_id"=>["22"], "f_id"=>["2066"], "user_id"=>"1"}, "order_parameters"=>{"is_worked_on"=>"DESC", "new_match_count"=>"DESC", "association_status_id"=>"DESC"}, "pagination_parameters"=>{"page"=>"1", "per_page"=>"10"}, "format"=>"json", "action"=>"index", "controller"=>"api/v1/tests"}
```

In after filter

```
{"search_params"=>{"d"=>"08/20/2014", "c_id"=>["22"], "f_id"=>["2066"]}, 
"order_parameters"=>{"is_worked_on"=>"DESC", "new_match_count"=>"DESC", "association_status_id"=>"DESC"}, "pagination_parameters"=>{"page"=>"1", "per_page"=>"10"}, "format"=>"json", "action"=>"index", "controller"=>"api/v1/tests"}
```

And i am pretty sure that we are not manipulating the object intentionally. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the code in `api/v1/tests#index` action?

Comment: Then perhaps you are manipulating the params unintentionally :-) call `params[:search_params].freeze` and `params.freeze` and attempts to change them will raise an exception

Answer (score 0):

Yes, params was modified at a nested level in separate module.